# It appears mutt does not recognize the use of HTML nth-child(odd) usage

Tags: scripting, mutt

In a Bash script, I build an HTML table in a file.  When I display it, it comes out the way I want:
[image]

When I want to include it in an email using **mutt**, it comes without the nth-child(odd) highlighted:
[image]

How do I get mutt to recognize the use of nth-child(odd)?

Comment: Is `mutt` the application in which you see this rendered wrongly? Or just the application that sends the message?

Comment: What helper application are you using to view the table in `mutt` with? As far as I know, `mutt` can't render HTML by itself.

Comment: Are you sending the html using mutt, or are you viewing the html in mutt (in which case Kusalananda's question is relevant)? To me it looks like you're relying on CSS which isn't available later. Perhaps edit your question to show exactly what HTML code you are using.

Comment: roaima - mutt is where it is rendered wrongly

Comment: Kusalananda - you can pass html files into mutt and it does render the html correctly except for the background color of blue for every odd row; this is where the nth-child(odd) is utilized

Comment: wurtel - the html file is being passed into mutt with content_type="text/html"  <style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 12px;
}

th {
  border: 2px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: lemonchiffon;
}

td {
  border: 2px solid #dddddd;
  padding: 6px;
  text-align: center;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) { background: LightCyan; }

</style>